# How to check a completed gzip file?

Tags: c, linux, gzip

I am writing a function in C that get a .tar.gz data transfer, when I got the data, I should do a check that whether the transfer is complete and the data is valid, so any tips about check the integrity of gzip data?

regards

Comment: Have you tried ungzipping it yet?

Comment: Sorry, I can not, just because I got the data from http post method and I need do a integrity check then write it to a file, afterwards, I can unzip the file, etc...

Comment: @liunx, The unzip process does an integrity check. You can also stream the decompress to a file, and delete it later if the stream is corrupt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`gunzip -t` checks the compressed file integrity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just downloading a tarball, then you can md5sum it on the other end and then check that.

Comment: Sorry, I can not, just because I got the data from http post method and I need do a integrity check then write it to a file, afterwards, I can unzip the file, etc...